# Why does numpy.save work only sometimes on Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, ubuntu

I am working on a project with a very long preprocessing step, so I wanted to process everything beforehand. After all the preprocessing steps I wanted to save the data using `np.save` as in the following sample

```
for i in range(len(data)):
            heatmap = generate_heatmap(data[i], min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y, img_size)
            save_file = os.path.join(save_folder, files[i]) + '.npy'
            transformed = full_transform(heatmap, (64, 64), (56, 56)).numpy()
            np.save(save_file, transformed)
```

but I get the following error:

```
 File "preprocessing_data.py", line 268, in <module>
    np.save(save_file, transformed)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in save
  File "/data/skostadinov/venv_samuel/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 522, in save
    format.write_array(fid, arr, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
  File "/data/skostadinov/venv_samuel/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 722, in write_array
    array.tofile(fp)
OSError: 53312 requested and 35808 written
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about this error, considering I'm working on Linux (Ubuntu 22 LTS) does anyone know what did go wrong?

Also I think it's strange since this does not happen always, because the first few data folders are elaborated without problems.

Comment: Maybe you've filled the disk?